# Retroactive Change to Default Script Width

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

I have someone's old python code that conforms to a 120 character width for the entirety of the project. Is there any option in PyCharm that can automatically convert the script to 80 character width limit, while still conforming to Pep-8 standards or something similar? I know I can change the option for where the vertical limit line actually shows in the script, but can anything actually manipulate the script itself to conform as well, instead of having every line just run over by 40 characters?

This is an extensive project, I would hate to spend half a day abusing the Enter key on every line.

Thanks

Comment: You can change the number of columns per line in the Settings at Code Style > Default Options > Right Margin. If you then format the code (CTRL-ALT-L), the editor will use that option to decide when to wrap lines. If you first select a directory in the Project View, PyCharm will format all files in that directory for you.

Comment: Okay in Code Style > Default Options > Wrapping and Brances i selected "ensure right margin not exceeded" and applied. However, when I then do CTRL-SHIFT-L I do not see anything regarding formatting. Do you mean CTRL-ALT-L ? Thanks!

Comment: CTRL-ALT-L, yes. Code > Reformat code in the top menu.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.